# how to find max value and its index number in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

in the python, I'm trying to find the max value of a numpy array with its index number.

in matlab `[val,I]=max(v)` , `val = "maximum value"` and `I = "index number"` witch `v` is a `1x12 double`

how could I implement this array in numpy?

also, I try this :

```
import numpy as np

v = np.empty([v_size,1])
for j in range(1,v_size):
   x1 = int(tmp[j - 1, 0])
   x2 = int(tmp[j - 1, 1])
   x3 = int(tmp[j + 1, 0])
   x4 = int(tmp[j + 1, 1])
   v[j] = image[x1, x2] - image[x3, x4]
if np.all(v == 0) == 0:
   val,I = np.amax(v)
```

I would be appreciated if anybody helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`amax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html):

```py
maxElement = numpy.amax(arr)
result = numpy.where(arr == numpy.amax(arr))
result[0] # Will be your max.
```

Or equivalent:

```py
max_num, index = [numpy.amax(arr), numpy.where(arr == numpy.amax(arr))[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check numpy documentation... There are at least two immediate ways to get what you want:

```
maxvalue = array.max()
maxindex = array.argmax()
```

Or:

```
maxvalue = np.max(array)
maxindex = np.argmax(array)
```

Comment: I find it ironic that you suggest that OP should read the docs. This question is an easy duplicate and so you shouldn't be answering it. Maybe you should read the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)...

Answer (score 0):

We can use ‘np.argmax’ and use the index to get the value. Performant way.

```
a=np.asarray((1,3,8,5,4))
m = np.argmax(a)
n = a[m]
print(“Max value: {} and its id: {}”.format(n, m))
Max value: 8 and it’s id: 2
```